# How can I fix this? Magento 2 REST API paypal payment successed but Order not creating and getting error in console?

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api, paypal-express, ionic

How can I fix this ? Magento 2 REST API paypal payment successed but Order not creating  and getting error in console !

[image]